Flutter and firebase firestore error while using streams
I have a flutter app that uses cloud firestore to store the user's tasks. I was trying to update the tasks in real time using a stream, but the page just shows a red error screen with the following error:
The following _TypeError was thrown building StreamBuilder<List<Task>>(dirty, state: _StreamBuilderBaseState<List<Task>, AsyncSnapshot<List<Task>>>#9db50):
type '(dynamic) => dynamic' is not a subtype of type '(Task) => bool' of 'test'

The relevant error-causing widget was:
    StreamBuilder<List<Task>> StreamBuilder:file:///C:/Users/dhair/OneDrive/Desktop/Coding/track_ai/lib/views/HomeDashboardNew.dart:26:15

Here is some relevant code:
  // Stream to fetch tasks from Firestore in real-time
  Stream<List<Task>> taskStream(String uid) {
    return _firestore
        .collection('users')
        .doc(uid)
        .snapshots()
        .asyncMap((userSnapshot) async {
      if (userSnapshot.exists && userSnapshot.data() != null) {
        List<dynamic> taskReferences = userSnapshot.data()!['tasks'] ?? [];

        // Convert the dynamic list to a list of DocumentReferences
        List<DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>>> taskRefs =
            taskReferences.cast<DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>>>();

        // Fetch tasks using the document references
        List<Task> tasks = [];
        for (DocumentReference<Map<String, dynamic>> ref in taskRefs) {
          DocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>> taskSnapshot = await ref.get();
          if (taskSnapshot.exists && taskSnapshot.data() != null) {
            tasks.add(Task.fromSnapshot(taskSnapshot.data()!));
          }
        }

        // for (Task task in tasks) {
        //   log({
        //     task.name,
        //     task.description,
        //     task.deadline,
        //     task.startTime,
        //     task.endTime,
        //     task.priority,
        //     task.isCompleted,
        //     task.progress
        //   }.toString());
        // } 


        return tasks as List<Task>;
      } else {
        return [];
      }
    });
  }

Surprisingly when I was logging the task in the console, it was working completely as intended, and there were no errors in the stream function.
Here is the usage of the taskStream function
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Track AI'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.blueAccent,
        ),
        body: StreamBuilder<List<Task>>( //error here
            stream: _firestoreDatabase.taskStream(uid),
            builder: (context, snapshot) {
              // Handle loading state
              if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              }

              // Handle errors
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
              }

              // Ensure we have data to work with
              if (!snapshot.hasData ||
                  snapshot.data == null ||
                  snapshot.data!.isEmpty) {
                return Center(child: Text('No tasks available.'));
              }

              // Extract tasks from snapshot
              List<Task> todaysTasks = snapshot.data!;
              // Code continued...

Also, here is my task model:

// Task Model
class Task {
  final String name;
  final DateTime? startTime;
  final DateTime? endTime;
  final String? description;
  final String priority;
  final DateTime deadline;
  final bool isCompleted;
  final double progress;

  Task({
    required this.name,
    this.startTime,
    this.endTime,
    required this.priority,
    this.description,
    required this.deadline,
    required this.isCompleted,
    required this.progress,
  });

  factory Task.fromSnapshot(Map<String, dynamic> snapshot) {
    return Task(
      name: snapshot['name'] ?? '',
      startTime: snapshot['startTime'] != null
          ? (snapshot['startTime'] as Timestamp).toDate()
          : null,
      endTime: snapshot['endTime'] != null
          ? (snapshot['endTime'] as Timestamp).toDate()
          : null,
      description: snapshot['description'] ?? '',
      priority: snapshot['priority'] ?? 'Low',
      deadline: (snapshot['deadline'] as Timestamp).toDate(),
      isCompleted: snapshot['isCompleted'] ?? false,
      progress: (snapshot['progress'] ?? 0.0).toDouble(),
    );
  }
}


